# Netilat yadayim in the presence of rotting food, splash back and berakha

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

Regarding morning teliah:

Can one do morning (or any really) netilah in the presence of a bad smell and/or physical presence of  rotting  food (not the berakha)?

If some drops of water splashes back from the basen onto the hands, are the hands still tamei?

If one already washed but did not make the berakha and went about daily tasks, should the berakha still be said at a later point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The halachos of netilas yadayim are brought down in [OC 4](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.4?lang=bi).

1. Absolutely. The issue is to remove ruach ra'ah. Saying certain things in the presence of foul smells are out of kavod to what is being said (such as davening). The reason doesn't apply to netilas yadayim and, as such, should be permissible.
2. Mishnah Berurah ad. loc. seif katan 21 says that one should not leave used netilas yadayim water where people might use it because they might be affected by the ruach ra'ah. So I would assume that the answer is yes, he needs to wash again to remove the ruach ra'ah.
3. You might not realize it, but you (might) do this already when you say Netilas Yadayim in davening. See OC 46:2 and Mishnah Berurah ad. loc. seif katan 11.